# How do I keep my section open after using .slideDown Jquery function on it?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get this function to slide down and stay down, but it keeps sliding back up.

```js
 $('.call-to-action').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#new-tweet').is(':hidden')) {
          ($('#new-tweet').slideDown());
        } else {
          ($('#new-tweet').slideUp());
        }
      });
```

```css
#new-tweet {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="new-tweet">
          <h2>Compose Tweet</h2>
    
          <form id="tweet-form" method="POST" action="/tweets">
        
          <label for="tweet-text"></label>
          //text area id="tweet=text" has no relevant css classes applied to it (just background color)
          <textarea id="tweet-text" name="text" placeholder="What are you humming about?"></textarea>
          <div class="button-count">
            <button type="submit" class="submit-tweeet">Tweet</button>
            <output name="counter" id="tx-counter" class="counter" for="tweet-text"></output>
          </div>
    
          </form>
        </section>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where is your click event button `call-to-action` ?

Comment: I fixed it! I had to remove a button element which was wrapping around my anchor element. Not sure if this is the best way to approach this?

`      <a class="call-to-action">
        <!-- <div class="call-to-action"> -->
        <span>Write a new tweet</span>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i>
      </a>`

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to properly put my code in a comment :) sorry for the har to read text

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use toggle would be more reasonable

```js
 $('.call-to-action').on('click', function() {
         $('#new-tweet').stop().toggle('slow');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.submit-tweeet').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#new-tweet').is(':hidden')) {
    ($('#new-tweet').slideDown());
  } else {
    ($('#new-tweet').slideUp());
  }
});
```

```css
#new-tweet {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="new-tweet">
  <h2>Compose Tweet</h2>

  <form id="tweet-form" method="POST" action="/tweets">

    <label for="tweet-text"></label> //text area id="tweet=text" has no relevant css classes applied to it (just background color)
    <textarea id="tweet-text" name="text" placeholder="What are you humming about?"></textarea>
    <div class="button-count">
      <button type="button" class="submit-tweeet">Tweet</button>
      <output name="counter" id="tx-counter" class="counter" for="tweet-text"></output>
    </div>

  </form>
</section>
```

The class is missing. please refer to this snippet